# PHPStorm 7 not uploading files to mapped network drive automatically after SVN update

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm experiencing strange PHPStorm 7 behavior - I'm using SVN, I have working copy on my HDD and I'm uploading data to mapped Drive in Windows 7 (when I update any directory, PhpStorm is not uploading files automatically to my network location (that's mapped drive in windows).

Also, sometimes it looks that I must upload same files manually *twice* to have it uploaded on my server. That's quite annoying.

Of course I've looked for some options, plugins or help on Jetbrains webpages, without success.
So the question is, why files are not uploading automatically and how to achieve it?

ver: 7.0, build: PS-131.374, JRE 1.7.0_10; VM: HotSpot srv; Windows 7 Pro SP1; 8 GB Ram PC; 
Network is working fine.

**EDIT: I have automatic upload enabled. **

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

go to Tools -> Deployment -> Options and check the checkbox 'Upload external changes'.

Tada :)

Answer (score 0):

**1.** Latest stable version is **7.1.3** -- consider upgrading from your 7.0

**2.** VCS changes are **considered external changes**, so unless you edit those changed files .. or configured to automatically upload external changes as well, they will not be transferred.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2171 -- subscribe to that ticket (vote/star/comment) to get notified on progress.

---

> Also, sometimes it looks that I must upload same files manually twice to have it uploaded on my server. That's quite annoying.

No clue -- you should check your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in...) for possible hints / exceptions. Quite likely it fails to upload those files for some reason.

Comment: Check my edit - I have automatic upload enabled - but that's not working after update. I must right click on directory and upload whole folder to my network location. It's not uploading automatically.

Comment: Screenshot please (yes, I'm not believer .. plus you could miss some another option).